# "Игнат" в форме притяжательного прилагательного -?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно пишется имя Игнат в форме притяжательного прилагательного?

Answer (score 3):

Игнатов ремень, Игнатова корова, Игнатово счастье, Игнатовы дети.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***Игнатов***. И не только пишется, но и произносится.

Рискну предположить, что проблема связана с формой Игнатьев, но она образована от имени Игнатий. 
Ну а то, что с заглавной, это общее правило.

> С прописной буквы пишутся притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами -ое- (ев), -ин-, образованные от собственных имён лиц,
>   животных, мифологических существ: Марсов гнев, Одиссеевы странствия,
>   Машино платье, Шарикова будка.

http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/orfografia/propis/3172/